# VBA To Create Backup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question on the macro events here. Below is my code. This performs the below Operations’

```
Private Sub SaveAsTabDelimited(ByVal sFileName As String)

  With ActiveWorkbook

    .SaveAs Filename:=sFileName, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=True

  End With

End Sub

Public Sub test()

  SaveAsTabDelimited "C:\Users\te160772\Desktop\Toad Test\Testsanthu.txt"

  ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

1. It converts the excel file into tab delimited txt file
2. It creates a backup copy of the excel file
   I wanted this action to be performed each day inorder the excel file to upload to Oracle tables on daily basis. The reason behind converting excel spreadsheet to tab delimited txt file is to preserve the format (To prevent the removal of leading zeros while exporting it to oracle)

But now I am trying to enhance this code so that the following actions should be performed without any glitch. I have tried to do this in all the possible ways .since I am very new to the programming I was not able to do this.

1. The code should convert the excel file to tab delimited save on my desktop (Hope that my current piece of code is sufficient for this action)
2. It should create a backup copy in a folder called “Repository” (A folder in a desktop). Each change to my workbook should result a backup copy with the version history if possible(Date and Time stamp in the file name)
3. the biggest problem associated with my code is that upon close, three separate dialogue boxes appear - one asking me if i want to save, the other asking me if i want to keep what i have copied in the clipboard, another one is replace the existing text file saved in the folder is there a way of answering these dialogue boxes (or suppressing them) from within the macro, so i do not need to manually click on yes or no each time the macro is run?
4. I have attached my macro to a “shape” in excel but my priority is to run my macro upon closing of my workbook. Every time when any changes happen to my workbook and when I save the workbook, it should create a tab delimited Text files which should replace the existing Txt File without any confirmation dialogue boxes.

Please help me on this. This is badly require for me

With a million thanks

Comment: If you've already tried to add this functionality, then you should post your code.  It doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: Please reduce your question that way that we have a clear picture of your technical issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The code should convert the excel file to tab delimited save on my desktop (Hope that my current piece of code is sufficient for this action)

Yes, either you can hardcode the path to the desktop or use this code to get the path to the desktop automatically

```
Sub GetDesktopPath()
    Dim oWS As Object
    Dim DskTopPath As String

    Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    DskTopPath = oWS.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

    Debug.Print DskTopPath

    Set oWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

> It should create a backup copy in a folder called “Repository” (A folder in a desktop). Each change to my workbook should result a backup copy with the version history if possible(Date and Time stamp in the file name)

You can use the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event to create a copy of the existing workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

You may want to explore `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` See Excel Help for more info.

---

> the biggest problem associated with my code is that upon close, three separate dialogue boxes appear - one asking me if i want to save, the other asking me if i want to keep what i have copied in the clipboard, another one is replace the existing text file saved in the folder is there a way of answering these dialogue boxes (or suppressing them) from within the macro, so i do not need to manually click on yes or no each time the macro is run?

You can get rid of these alerts by simply sandwiching your code between

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'~~> Your Code
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

If you are using clipboard a lot, then you might also want to clear it by using

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

---

> I have attached my macro to a “shape” in excel but my priority is to run my macro upon closing of my workbook. Every time when any changes happen to my workbook and when I save the workbook, it should create a tab delimited Text files which should replace the existing Txt File without any confirmation dialogue boxes.

You can use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event to run your relevant code

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

Regarding the alert, I have already explained that in the previous section.

Hope this sets you in the right path.

Comment: Hi Siddharth,   This is what i was looking for. Thanks a lot for your kind support